# Storing JSON Data in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, bitcoin

How would I store data from a JSON Object from the Blockchain Exchange Rates API: 
https://blockchain.info/ticker into a NSString?

This is what I have so far:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://blockchain.info/ticker"];
NSData *rate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rate options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"Data%@", [dic description]);

NSString *response = [dic valueForKey:@"USD"];
NSLog(@"Last: %@", response);
```

From the NSLog I get:

```
{
    15m = "656.01";
    last = "656.01";
    buy = "656.01"; 
    sell = "656.45";
    symbol = "$";
}
```

How do I get only the `last` value (store the number 656.01 by itself?

Comment: hi bro, what the result u need or which result u need

Comment: "How do I get only the last value?"  Ask for it - `dic[@"USD"][@"last"]`.

Comment: I wanted to get: `"656.01"` from `last = "656.01";` Sorry for being unclear. I got the answer now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is a JSON dictionary, where the value for each entry is also a dictionary. The natural thing to do, then, is to turn it into an actual NSDictionary using NSJSONSerialization. Then you can do whatever you like with it -- you could store it as a property list for example.

Comment: Could you tell me how to get the `last` value by code?

Comment: One way is: `NSString *s = dic[@"USA"][@"last"];`, which is just a shorter way to write what others have already told you.